# Obtain a list of files in Terminal in same order as in Finder

Tags: terminal

I have a folder of about 1,000 image files. I need to create a list of them. I saw somewhere that if I go into Terminal and cd into the folder, all I have to do is type in

ls > list.csv

to generate a list.
The thing is, this list is not in the same order as the files I see in Finder. For example, in Finder, the first image is 16_left.jpg. However, the first image in the generated list.csv file is 10017_left.jpg, whilst 16_left.jpg is snuggled all the way down in between 15975_right.jpg and 16007_right.jpg.

I can see that in Finder, it sees the number 16 as being the smallest in the files and puts that top, whereas the list.csv file sorts the list not by the whole number itself but by each individual digit left-to-right.

How do I get list.csv to be in the same order as Finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/
and got the answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716914/obtain-a-list-of-files-in-terminal-in-same-order-as-in-finder?noredirect=1#comment1359014_716914

Basically the command to use is: `print -rC1 -- *.jpg(NDn) > list.csv`

Do upvote their (more fleshed-out) answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716917/540974) as it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your finder shows to you files ordered by creation time from the newest to oldest. ls with no arguments list by name order.

`ls -lt` will list by creation order from newest to oldest

Comment: Good suggestion but the files were all created at the same time (they were downloaded in one big zip fie). I have just checked; list2.csv is still not in the same order as I can see in Finder.

Comment: Can I add the tag Unix here as well? Or will I get downvoted for that

Comment: Even files comes from a zip somewhere in time they were created before zipped. This previous creation still stays on

Comment: Pay look to details. ls -la shows you creation date you will see main point.